# How to set QoS priority (TOS) on packets leaving specific adapter (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, qos

I need to configure 2 Ethernet adapters so that each of them tags their packet with a specific QoS priority.  For example, adapter A would generate packets with a priority of 0, while adapter B would generate packets with priority 60.

I tried configuring a group policy and I have been able to set a priority (DSCP), validated with WireShark.  However, even if I specify a specific source IP address, both adapters generate packets with the same priority.

[image: Wireshark/gpedit]

Setting 2 group policies, one with 0 and the other with 60 doesn't help either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Any other suggestion how I could easily tag packets on specific interfaces connected to the same PC?**

Thank you!

Comment: You need to understand what you are connecting to. Many switches, by default, will reset any QoS markings back to `0`, but routers typically will not. QoS is an end-to-end thing, and you need to make sure it is configured on all the network devices between you and the end-device. That is why QoS doesn't work on the Internet.

Comment: I'm testing a managed switch.  Anyway, Wireshark shows the packets before they get to the switch, and the priority is set for both adapters instead of just one of them.

Comment: You may want to double-check your switch. We ended up doing all the marking on the switches.

Comment: Well, setting priorities on the switch itself works fine (port-based priorities).  It's a switch we are designing...  I need to set the priority tag on the host, and let the switch assign a queue to that tag.